# CSS3 Columns and UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, css

Using CSS3 columns to take a somewhat large text document and make it scroll horizontally. I want each column to be close to the size of the iPad screen, as I am displaying the content in a UIWebView.

If I make the -webkit-column-width: property a relatively small number, everything works great. The text stops at the max-height set for the containing  and columns out horizontally.

If I make -webkit-column-width anything larger than about 300px, though, this css seems to get completely ignored. The text displays vertically as it would without styling. Any fixes?

Display when -webkit-column-width is 325px. The view scrolls to the right normally:

[image: 325]

Display when -webkit-column-width is 500px. Text appears as one column and the view scrolls downward to the end of the document, ignoring max-height:
[image: 500]

Comment: Can you post a screen-shot - not entirely clear what's happening from your question

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to divide, let's say, `600px` wide container into X `500px` wide columns. Browser renders only one column because it can't put 2 (or more) `500px` wide columns in `600px` wide container. First of all - by default, the browser will stretch your content vertically, to make it stretch it horizontally you have to specify fixed `height` for the container and `width` needs to be set to `auto` (which is default). Of course you need to adjust this values so columns will fit iPads viewport.

Here is demo of code, that should work properly - http://jsfiddle.net/wojtiku/bFKpa/

```
#container {
    height: 300px;
    -webkit-column-width: 150px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
}
```

*NOTE: I don't have iPad, tested on desktop.*